# Index was out of the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

This is my program with error:

> index was out of the bounds of array

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;

namespace command
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name is " + args[1]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you feeding Main? You should be checking that args actually has data at those indices before you try to retrieve it.

Comment: Are you calling the program with 2 inputs?  Like "program.exe john doe"

Comment: the following code does not run ;

Comment: just throws error "index was out of bounds array"

Comment: first of all, did you supplied the arguments?

Comment: i dint supply any arguments can u edit my entire code

Comment: i cant input anything as the code doesnt run

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not passing any parameters to your program. You can do this by running your program from the command line, or if you are running this through Visual Studio, you can set the arguments to pass by going to the project properties, selecting the Debug tab, and entering them into the Start options section.

[image: Visual Studio Project Properties]

Answer (score 0):

You have to check how many command line parameters are *actually provided*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;

namespace command
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args) { 
         if (args.Length > 0)
           Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + args[0]);

         if (args.Length > 1)
           Console.WriteLine("Last Name is " + args[1]);

         Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
  # No parameters
  c:\MyProgram.exe 

  # One parameter 
  c:\MyProgram.exe FirstNameOnly 

  # Two parameters 
  c:\MyProgram.exe FirstName LastName
```

Comment: @DION: please, ensure that you run the modified (rebuilt) version. At what line do you have the exception thrown?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + args[0]);@Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @DION: I can't reproduce the misbehavior with my code. So you have to debug: check if don't you do a hidden error, e.g. `if (args.Length > 0);` - the semicolon that spoils the fun. Put a breakpoint on `if (args.Length > 0)` examine the `args` array

Comment: @DION - The code provided is complete.  How are you testing the code?  Are you pressing F5 to run the program?  How do you execute the program?

Comment: no hidden error@Dmitry Bychenko still throws error at the line  Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + args[0]);

Comment: Yes I pressed f5 as well as the debug button in visual studio 2010 ultimate  it thorws error.I allow tested in command line same over there @Chris Dunaway

Comment: If you pressed F5, what parameters did you pass into the program?

Answer (score 0):

This relies on the idea that you are passing a minimum of two arguments, but you are not verifying this first. If you don't want output unless the user has met a minimum of two arguments, then using a try{} block, and catch an out of bounds array with a response to the user to use a minimum of two arguments.

```
   static void Main(string[] args) { 
       try{
       Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + args[0]);

        Console.WriteLine("Last Name is " + args[1]);

        Console.ReadLine();
   }catch (OutOfBoundsException exception){
     MessageBox.Show("Insufficient input parameters");
   }
```

You could also use an if(args.Length == 2) to determine if this is enough without using a try{}.

Answer (score 0):

You always must check the size of the args array. 
SO...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if ( args.Count() >= 2 )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name is " + args[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `args.Count` doesn't compile. `args.Length` or `args.Count()` in case of *Linq*

Comment: Correctamundo Dmitry - I elided the parens. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: can anyone explain me this line:x[i]=(char)(x[i]+3);@Dmitry Bychenko

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    if(args.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name is " + args[1]);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No Command Line Arguments were passed");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and pass the command line arguments as explained by [David_001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209578/david-001).

Comment: `if (args.Length > 1)`; otherwise you'll have the exception thrown on `myProg.exe JustFirstName` command line

Comment: @DmitryBychenko doesn't this condition `if(args.Length > 0)` satisfies it?

Comment: since you've put `"Last Name is " + args[1]` (please, notice, `1`) you have to write `if (args.Length > 1)` to be sure that `args[1]` exists.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes! that's a precise check... :)